# Make drawable do centerCrop in layer-list

Tags: android, splash-screen, image-resizing

all.

I want to make splashscreen:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/background_splash:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/main_theme"/>

<item android:bottom="16dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        />
</item>

<item android:bottom="16dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</item>
```

But I have no ability to make bitmap with android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" resize as centerCrop scale in ImageView( I need my bitmap fill all width) For now it's size as size in resource in pixels. If i make it much larger it will be larger the screen. I tried scale drawable and no sense.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this one?

Comment: No, for those issue it wasn't possible. Maybe something changed since then. All you can do is to make some drawable be e.g. 100dp.

Comment: okay I see, thank for responding.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve filling screen, but keep in mind, it will be a bit stretched on 18:9 screens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_2_x2"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: For filling the screen you just need the gravity property like `android:gravity="fill"`, but this will not achieve centerCrop as the question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Change this Line to

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

To

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

because android:windowsBackground attribute will not  be able to show splash at  full screen. It's good way u use  android:background for splash. Then if you want  you can call centercrop in your Splash Activity. Hope  this helped!!

Comment: Thanks, but It have the same result

Comment: Does your splash Image displaying in the full screen?

Comment: No, now it has 60-70% of the width. I think at different screeen sizes it has different result. 60-90%

Comment: Crop image at  3 different  size ldpi, mdpi and hdpi and put those images  in mipmap and call them from mipmap like @mipmap/logo and @mipmap/splash_logo. This  is the  only way to fit  images in all size  of  Android Phone  and  tablet see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: One more  solution you may find helpful is you can define       
  <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item> in styles.xml just give it a try, define this in your styles.xml

Comment: `android:background` is a view attribute, not a theme attribute. Never use it in your themes.