# Make background image in splash screen center crop

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme

I used a image as a picture for my slash screen.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

However, in some different devices, it has been stretched and distorted. Is there a way to make the photo centercrop like in ImageView?

Comment: this link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082029/make-drawable-do-centercrop-in-layer-list

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212977/android-center-splash-screen-image

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly setting an image , try setting it from a xml drawable  this might you a better control over the image .

You can follow the steps shown here:-

[Splash the right way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

Answer (score 0):

If your drawable is a bitmap image then you have to change the `android:gravity` attribute to `"center"` on the `bitmap` element of the drawable's resource.

The default value is `"fill"` which *"Grow the horizontal and vertical size of the object if needed so it completely fills its container."*. [More xml bitmap info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#XmlBitmap).

For example drawable/background_splash.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/colorAccent"></color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:antialias="true"
        />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: set gravity to center only place the drawable in the middle, it doesn't do center crop as ImageView. It should both scale up and crop the drawable.

Comment: True, I missed the "crop" part. While centering, my solution will not guarantee that both dimensions of the image are equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the splash screen. To achieve this (scaling) using my solution you would have to carefully choose the size of the splash image for each of the its screen density buckets (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, ...).

Answer (score -3):

**Try this solution**

First of all get the splash screen image resized in different sizes and put them in `drawable` folders like `drawable-mpdi,drawable-hpdi,drawable-xhpdi,drawable-xxhpdi,drawable-xxxpdi`

[image: directory like this]

```
360x640 - mdpi 
540x960 - hpdi
720x1280 - xhpdi
1080x1920 - xxhpdi
1440x2560 - xxxhpdi
```

Then in `xml` of splash activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Or simply define the `drawable` in style for the particular activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It seems you didn't get my question